# Customize gnome lock screen for the date appearing

Tags: gnome, lock-screen

I've looked for previously asked questions about the lock screen customising. Also for changing the date format but could not find any answer. There is a question about KDE Plasma. But this is totally different.

Also checked the configuration file .css but could not find any thing.

So I'd like to display date as January 25, 2019 or 2019-01-25 etc.

How can I do that?

Comment: are you looking to customize only this part on lock screen? have you tried changing the format in gnome-shell and see if the same applied?

Comment: Yes. I just want to change this part. Maybe later add some weather information, etc.